# Will SpaceX's moon mission carry any engineers to fix the craft or will the artists be trained for these operations?

Tags: spacex, the-moon, crewed-spaceflight

In the live stream, Elon Musk mentioned that a dozen would be the ideal size for a mission. Could have easily been an off the cuff range, but would allow for some engineers if something goes wrong.

Haven't seen any official confirmation.

`6 artists + Yusaku = 7 passengers so 5 engineers (or 4 + Elon)`

or

`8 artists + Yusaku = 9 passengers so 3 engineers (or 2 + Elon)`

Answer (score 7):

The Space.com article [How SpaceX's 1st Passenger Flight Around the Moon with Yusaku Maezawa Will Work](https://www.space.com/41856-how-spacex-bfr-moon-passenger-flight-works.html) contains a slide show with more information from SpaceX.

Slide 15 confirms SpaceX crew members in addition to the ones announced:

> Launch phase
>
> Like any major space mission, Maezawa's flight will begin at liftoff.
>   While early tests of the BFR spaceship will likely occur at SpaceX's southern Texas proving ground near Brownsville, the actual rocket may launch from a different site or from an offshore platform, Musk has said.
>
> Maezawa's flight will not carry a full complement of 100 passengers but rather only the select few he chooses to join him **and any SpaceX pilots or astronauts that may be required.** (emphasis added)

Comment: 100 people is absolutely huge given that until now the largest number of people concurrently in space anywhere has been .. 13.

Answer (score 5):

I really suspect that a dozen people will be on the mission. So your numbers are correct. If nothing else, no one is going to pay hundreds of millions of dollars and then want to clean the toilets and fix the spacecraft, someone will have to be on hand to do those tasks. Also likely a pilot, who will also help with that kind of stuff, will be on board.

Comment: A flight surgeon would also be prudent.

Comment: There are already [volunteers](https://twitter.com/StationCDRKelly/status/1042035279152984064) to help with the spacecraft, not sure if Cdr Scott Kelley is saying he wants to clean up after rich people though.

Comment: @DrSheldon: ... to take care of the engineer in case something goes wrong.

Comment: @DrSheldon like the engineer starting to talk to themselves?

Answer (score 1):

Yusaku Maezawa posted an answer to this on his twitter feed: "After a press conference, we talked a lot at Elon's home. He said that it would be reliable if 1-2 astronauts will be on board."

Source: https://twitter.com/yousuck2020/status/1042331987841703936